# change point detection of time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, data-preprocessing, change-point

Currently, I am working on a research project that involves forecasting electricity consumption using data mining. In my analysis, I have detected the change point for time series using the changepoint package for my data sets using the "AMOC", PELT," and "BinSeg" methods. For each method, I have used var, mean, and meanvar. However, I have encountered a problem in identifying a change point that occurred during the pandemic period in 2020.

```
library(readxl)
library(changepoint)
tsdata <- ts(mydata$DOM, start = c(1997,1), frequency = 12)
amoc_cp <- cpt.var(tsdata, method = "AMOC")
amoc_cp <- cpt.mean(tsdata, method = "AMOC")
amoc_cp <- cpt.meanvar(tsdata, method = "AMOC")

 # Use the PELT method to detect change points in the time series using var , mean and meanvar as above
pelt_cp <- cpt.meanvar(tsdata, method = "PELT")

 # Use the BinSeg method to detect change points in the time series using var , mean and meanvar
Binseg_cp <- cpt.meanvar(tsdata, method = "BinSeg")


 # Print the location and value of each change point using the AMOC method
for (i in 1:length(amoc_cp@cpts)) {
+   cat("AMOC change point for diff", i, "at location", amoc_cp@cpts[i], "with value", tsdata[amoc_cp@cpts[i]], "\n")

# Plot the time series with change points
plot(tsdata, main = "Time Series with AMOC_MEAN Change Points")
# Add vertical lines at the locations of the change points
abline(v = index(tsdata)[ amoc_cp@cpts], col = "blue")
```

these code doesn't identify the visible change point as
[image]

when run the above code for differentiated time series it clearly indicate there is a change point in 2020 march, isnt it should be indicate for original data set too? if so how should I detect the change in 2020 statistically?

Comment: Welcome to CV. That looks more like an outlier or "transient" than a change point: after a few months, the series appears to return to what you would have expected before the pandemic.  This suggests thinking a little more about defining what you mean by "change point" and choosing an appropriate method to identify such things.  In light of this, what is your question?  You haven't asked one.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I was planing to  predict data for before pandemic  and after pandemic, after finding where is the change happened in 2021 year. when run the above code for differentiated time series  it clearly indicate there is a change point in 2020 march, isnt it should be indicate for original data set too? i thought there was a error in my code.  and theres more condition for change point detection.

Comment: You haven't addressed @whuber 's point, which is that this doesn't look like a change point but rather an outlier or short-lived transient effect.

Comment: There is a clear change in intercept around 2014 alongside a potential change in variance.  I agree that the outlier segment is a larger immediate issue but changepoint detection can handle both (a changepoint segment of length 2 is an outlier!).

Comment: Two points. First the variance increases substantially and then decreases substantially a short time later. Many changepoint detection methods struggle with two changepoints in quick succession. Also, the changepoint is near the end of the time series which for many methods makes it harder to detect.

Answer (score 2):

Some observations are that your code for AMOC is overwriting the three different methods as the names are the same.  The final method you fit is change in mean and variance of a Normal distribution, which you plot.  There are no plots of the PELT output which is fitting multiple changepoints

More importantly, all the models you fit are for (flat) mean or variance shifts.  There is clearly a trend in your data.  AMOC places a changepoint almost at the centre because when you fit a flat mean before and a flat mean after the change, this is the best place to put a single change.  If you look at the corresponding PELT plot, you will likely have a step function where every few observations a changepoint will be there to capture the increasing trend.

See the following two papers for descriptions of common pitfalls and a worked-through data example for constructing changepoint methods.

[1] Good Practices and Common Pitfalls in Climate Time Series Changepoint Techniques: A Review https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.02674 these points don't just apply to climate series

[2] Changepoint Detection: An Analysis of the Central England Temperature Series https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.12180
walkthrough with discussion

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additional thoughts. If treated as a time series decomposition problem, your data may be thought symbolically as `Y= 'Trend/PiecewiseLinear' + Outlier + error`. Apparently, numerous ways are possible to do the inference and detect the associated changepoints, most likely with inconsistent results among  statistical methods. Let me use a Bayesian time series analysis package Rbeast I developed (more info available at https://github.com/zhaokg/Rbeast) to demonstrate this decomposition.

In R, first make a simulated signal with a two-piece trend (the first segment is a flat line and the second segment is a linear line) plus three outlier-type changes.

```
 set.seed(123)

 # the 1st seg is flat and the 2nd segment is linear
 y =  c(   (1:50)*0,  1:50  )  +  rnorm(100)*2  

 # Add artificial dips/spikes at three isolated points to mimic outlier-type changepoints
 y[30] = y[30]+20 
 y[69] = y[69]-20
 y[70] = y[70]+20
 plot(y, type='l')
```

[image: The simulated time series data]

Then, run the time series decomposition to estimate the trend (i.e., piecewise linear model) and outlier components, together with possible changepoints.

```
library(Rbeast)
out = beast(y, season='none', hasOutlier=TRUE)
plot(out)
```

[image]

where the `prob(tcp)` subplot shows the probability of changepoint occurrence over time in the trend component and the single peak indicates that there is just one possible changepoint, and the `outlier` subplot shows the outlier component. The three salient outliers are detected but apparently there is a model overfitting because some other smaller extreme values also have decent probabilities of being outlier-type changepoints.

This may be not that useful for your specific applications, but hopefully it at least provides some alternative perspectives.